# Create Jquery Mobile Widgets/Components Dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

We can create a **button component** on the fly by using the following code,

```
var $page = '<div/>'

$("<a>", {text: "Button"}).
     buttonMarkup({
        inline: false,
        mini: true,
        icon: "check"
     }).on("click", function () {
          //Click Function
     }
  ).appendTo($page);
```

Like this how to create other JQM components/widgets or suggest me where to find that methods/events in the JQuery Mobile Docs.

***Question updated on 10-12-13***

Please check the following code

```
<!DOCTYPE html >    
    <head> 
        <title>:::: DYNAMIC JQM PAGE ::::: </title>     
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">  
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" charset="utf-8">     
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css"/> 
           <script src="js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>       
        <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                   $(function () {
                       var page = $("<div/>", {
                   "data-role":"page"
               }).append($("<h1/>")
                          .text("This is   Header"))
                          .appendTo($.mobile.container);
                   })
               </script>
    </head>  
    <body> 

   </body> 
</html>
```

above code is not working while creating a mobile page in the document body. How do i achieve this?...

Comment: I don't think anyone is going to list all the components here. You should read the [docs](http://api.jquerymobile.com/category/widgets/).

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply..I tried that as per the docs. but some of them not working properly. Is there any procedure to follow to create the widgets or practical solutions while creating them?..Thank you

Comment: Any widget can work that way, you just need to make sure that you fulfill widget structure. here's a demo of a collapsible http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/sZPv7/